# how to get path of the file to be deleted from the server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-io

i want to delete a file present in directory on the server. I have tried following code but code inside the file.exist never runs. It always skips it showing me that file does not exist. But file is present. can smone please help me. Thanx in advance

```
string filename = "Template\\copy.jpg";
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
string fileName = Server.MapPath(@"/Template/copy.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Server.MapPath` to get the path. e.g.

```
string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Template/copy.jpg");
System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
```

Comment: You might need to call ResolveUrl on the "~/" path before passing that to Server.MapPath.